# How to reverse text in a file in C?

Tags: c, file, reverse

I'm try to get my text to be read back to front and to be printed in the reverse order in that file, but my for loop doesn't seem to working. Also my while loop is counting 999 characters even though it should be 800 and something (can't remember exactly), I think it might be because there is an empty line between the two paragraphs but then again there are no characters there.

Here is my code for the two loops -:

```
/*Reversing the file*/
char please;
char work[800];
int r, count, characters3;

characters3 = 0;
count = 0;
r = 0;
fgets(work, 800, outputfile);

while (work[count] != NULL)
{
characters3++;
count++;
}

printf("The number of characters to be copied is-: %d", characters3);

for (characters3; characters3 >= 0; characters3--)
{
please = work[characters3];
work[r] = please;
r++;
}
 fprintf(outputfile, "%s", work);


/*Closing all the file streams*/
fclose(firstfile);
fclose(secondfile);
fclose(outputfile);
/*Message to direct the user to where the files are*/
printf("\n Merged the first and second files into the output file 
and reversed it! \n Check the outputfile text inside the Debug folder!");
```

Comment: I think that you need to process except for newline. E.g `"abc\n"` => `"cba\n"`.

Comment: I recommend opening the file in `binary` mode so that no translations take place, especially line endings.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: are you sure about that? If OP is working on a system with double character line endings (i.e. Windows), then those would be reversed as well. (Actually, this should be prevented by *not including the return at all* - surely OP  would not want the return at the start of the new line!)

Comment: `fgets(work, 800, outputfile);` ? You're "getting" from your output file? Then later your `fprintf(outputfile, "%s", work);` to the *same file* ? Please update your post to be a [minimal, **complete**, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: This would be a perfect opportunity for you to learn to use a debugger to step through the code, so you can see what it's actually doing. It's one of the best tools to use to figure out problems with your code, and learning to use it early while you're first learning to code will make the learning process much easier.

Comment: @RadLexus:  Opening the file in binary mode may help with correcting the character count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of *huge* conceptual flaws in your code.

The very first one is that you state that it "doesn't seem to [be] working" without saying why you think so. Just running your code reveals what the problem is: you do not get *any* output at all.

Here is why. You reverse your string, and so the terminating zero comes at the start of the new string. You then print that string – and it ends immediately at the first character.

Fix this by decreasing the start of the loop in `characters3`.

Next, why not *print* a few intermediate results? That way you can *see* what's happening.

```
string: [This is a test.
]
The number of characters to be copied is-: 15
result: [
.tset aa test.
]
```

Hey look, there seems to be a problem with the carriage return (it ends up at the start of the line), which is exactly what should happen – after all, it is part of the string – but more likely not what you intend to do.

Apart from that, you can clearly *see* that the reversing itself is not correct!

The problem now is that you are reading and writing from the *same string*:

```
please = work[characters3];
work[r] = please;
```

You write the character at the end into position #0, decrease the end and increase the start, and repeat until done. So, the second half of reading/writing starts copying the **end** characters back from the start into the **end** half again!

Two possible fixes: 1. read from one string and write to a new one, or 2. adjust the loop so it stops copying after 'half' is done (since you are doing **two** swaps per iteration, you only need to loop **half** the number of characters).

You also need to think more about what *swapping* means. As it is, your code *overwrites* a character in the string. To correctly swap two characters, you need to save one first in a temporary variable.

```
void reverse (FILE *f)
{
    char please, why;
    char work[800];
    int r, count, characters3;

    characters3 = 0;
    count = 0;
    r = 0;
    fgets(work, 800, f);

    printf ("string: [%s]\n", work);

    while (work[count] != 0)
    {
        characters3++;
        count++;
    }
    characters3--; /* do not count last zero */
    characters3--; /* do not count the return */

    printf("The number of characters to be copied is-: %d\n", characters3);

    for (characters3; characters3 >= (count>>1); characters3--)
    {
        please = work[characters3];
        why = work[r];
        work[r] = please;
        work[characters3] = why;
        r++;
    }
    printf ("result: [%s]\n", work);
}
```

As a final note: you do not need to 'manually' count the number of characters, there is a function for that. All that's needed instead of the `count` loop is this;

```
characters3 = strlen(work);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm still new to c and this is for a uni assignment.

Comment: I have done everything as shown, it seems as though the text from my file is not in the array. I tried printing the string before the reversing loop, and it just printed dashes on the display.

Comment: @SalmaElenin: I am sorry to hear that. I tested my function on its own and I am sure it works correctly. This needs debugging and troubleshooting on your side: test if the function itself works correctly, if your file gets read, and - given that you are attempting to read and write to separate files - that all `fopen`s have the correct reading/writing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete and heavily commented function that will take in a filename to an existing file, open it, then reverse the file character-by-character. Several improvements/extensions could include:

1. Add an argument to adjust the maximum buffer size allowed.
2. Dynamically increase the buffer size as the input file exceeds the original memory.
3. Add a strategy for recovering the original contents if something goes wrong when writing the reversed characters back to the file.

```c
// naming convention of l_ for local variable and p_ for pointers
// Returns 1 on success and 0 on failure 
int reverse_file(char *filename) {
    FILE *p_file = NULL;

    // r+ enables read & write, preserves contents, starts pointer p_file at beginning of file, and will not create a
    // new file if one doesn't exist. Consider a nested fopen(filename, "w+") if creation of a new file is desired.
    p_file = fopen(filename, "r+");
    // Exit with failure value if file was not opened successfully
    if(p_file == NULL) {
        perror("reverse_file() failed to open file.");
        fclose(p_file);
        return 0;
    }

    // Assumes entire file contents can be held in volatile memory using a buffer of size l_buffer_size * sizeof(char)
    uint32_t l_buffer_size = 1024;
    char l_buffer[l_buffer_size]; // buffer type is char to match fgetc() return type of int

    // Cursor for moving within the l_buffer
    int64_t l_buffer_cursor = 0;

    // Temporary storage for current char from file
    // fgetc() returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.
    int l_temp;

    for (l_buffer_cursor = 0; (l_temp = fgetc(p_file)) != EOF; ++l_buffer_cursor) {
        // Store the current char into our buffer in the original order from the file
        l_buffer[l_buffer_cursor] = (char)l_temp; // explicitly typecast l_temp back down to signed char
        // Verify our assumption that the file can completely fit in volatile memory <= l_buffer_size * sizeof(char)
        // is still valid. Return an error otherwise.
        if (l_buffer_cursor >= l_buffer_size) {
            fprintf(stderr, "reverse_file() in memory buffer size of %u char exceeded. %s is too large.\n",
                    l_buffer_size, filename);
            fclose(p_file);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // At the conclusion of the for loop, l_buffer contains a copy of the file in memory and l_buffer_cursor points
    // to the index 1 past the final char read in from the file. Thus, ensure the final char in the file is a
    // terminating symbol and decrement l_buffer_cursor by 1 before proceeding.
    fputc('\0', p_file);
    --l_buffer_cursor;

    // To reverse the file contents, reset the p_file cursor to the beginning of the file then write data to the file by
    // reading from l_buffer in reverse order by decrementing l_buffer_cursor.
    // NOTE: A less verbose/safe alternative to fseek is: rewind(p_file);
    if ( fseek(p_file, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0 ) {
       return 0;
    }

    for (l_temp = 0; l_buffer_cursor >= 0; --l_buffer_cursor) {
        l_temp = fputc(l_buffer[l_buffer_cursor], p_file); // write buffered char to the file, advance f_open pointer
        if (l_temp == EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "reverse_file() failed to write %c at index %lu back to the file %s.\n",
                    l_buffer[l_buffer_cursor], l_buffer_cursor, filename);
        }
    }
    fclose(p_file);
    return 1;
}
```